# Store java object which contains another object on a single table with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm doing an exercise with Springboot that basically consists of a simple application with a Rest Controller who has to store an object received from POST request to a mysql db using JPA/Hibernate.
My problem is the following one:

the table has this structure:

[image]

And I have this pojo which has to map the table as an object:

[image]

If you pay attention, the table has a column named "CARD_HOLDER_FULL_NAME", but in the app, the card holder must be a separate object:

[image]

so, how do I specify that the fullName attribuite in the CaldHolderInfo class represents that column in the table?

I'm very rusty with Springboot/JPA/hibernate so I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `CaldHolderInfo` an Embeddable.

See [JPA @Embedded And @Embeddable](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable)

And please, no images of code on this site.